# Touch and Swipe events not getting triggered

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I set up a click listener in the code below, but swipe and tape event handlers are not getting called. Any idea why?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.view);

    getOverflowMenu();

    android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager loaderManager = 
        getSupportLoaderManager();

    android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> loader = 
        loaderManager.getLoader(loader_id);

    if (loader != null) 
        loaderManager.initLoader(loader_id, null, this);
    else 
        loaderManager.restartLoader(loader_id,null,this);

    recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"touched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
         }
    });

    new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"moved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            long id = (long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();
            remove(id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `COMPLETE(11)` - is this homework?

Comment: You need to think harder about what you're asking people to do FOR you. If you want help here, format your code nicely. Remove unnecessary comments, make it *easy* to read. Don't include more code than necessary to show the problem, and ask very clear easy to understand questions, and state them intelligently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in activity with the recycle views (look like Main perhaps)

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "swiped left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           //do something awsome
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "swiped right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //do something awesomer
            }
        }

    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


}
```